# .babelrc breaking semantic-ui and next app

Tags: semantic-ui, babeljs, package.json, next.js

I am not sure what went on, but whenever I wanted to add unit testing to my app, I had to add `.babelrc` file with just the following code:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "next/babel"
  ]
}
```

Prior to that, I did not need the file and it was just an nextjs app with semantic. So far, so good. Until I decided to rebuild my semantic-ui theme which turned out to be a massive mistake!

This was what I ran: `cd semantic && gulp build`

This caused my app to stop working whenever `.babelrc` is present.

These are my `package.json` scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "semantic": "cd semantic && gulp build",
    "test": "mocha --require babel-core/register --watch-extensions js **/*.test.js"
  },
```

If I attempt to run the `next` related scripts, I get the following error:

> Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/theJuls/Workspace/cbt/client/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/lib/index.js

If I try to run my unit tests, I get

> Error: Plugin 0 specified in "/Users/theJuls/Workspace/cbt/client/node_modules/next/babel.js" provided an invalid property of "default" (While processing preset: "/Users/theJuls/Workspace/cbt/client/node_modules/next/babel.js")

If I remove `.babelrc`, all the `next` scripts run normally, however I completely lost my unit tests. Why is this happening? What can I do to fix this?

I am not sure if this is relevant but here is my current file structure:

```
api/
components/
config/
lib/
pages/
semantic/
store/
.babelrc
package-lock.json
package.json
semantic.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why it suddenly broke, but I have figured out a way around it which is also the more up to date way to do it, as my previous one was deprecated.

First off I had to install the following modules: `@babel/core` and `@babel/register`

Changed the `.babelrc` file to as follows:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "next/babel"
  ]
}
```

Finally, in `package.json` just slightly change the `test` command to:

> "test": "mocha --require @babel/register --watch-extensions js **/*.test.js"

Since we are now using `@babel/register`

This made everything come back to normal.